# invalid syntax for unknown reason

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I'm doing some django stuffs using vs code and this error in the line 3 ("from") happend for no reason.

```
from django.urls import path
from * import views
urlpatterns = [path(" ",views,name="home")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second import seems to be incorrect.

The syntax should be:

```
from <module> import <library / *>
```

In your case, it should be:

```
from views import *
```

That should be correct, as long as the views module do exist and can be found by python.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import like `from *`. Python expects a package name after `from`. If you are trying to import it from the relative path it might be something like

`from . import views`

Its a valid syntax error, and it did not happen for no-reason!

Comment: it removed the problem but the error now is in the line 1 and it says "No name 'urls' in module 'django'"

Comment: I solved this by running "pip install pylint" inside my virtual environment